# Using argument to call PHP in shell script

Tags: php, shell, cron, argument-passing

I have the following line in a shell script:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/script_to_run.php;
```

This works fine with our setup, until I add an argument like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/script_to_run.php?needed_variable=1;
```

At which point, I get the "Could not open input file" error.

Ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no query string in the command line;  you need to use arguments instead:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/script_to_run.php 1;
```

You then access the value with the [`$argv` variable](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.argv.php):

```
$value = $argv[1];
```

For more advanced command line argument parsing, take a look at [`getopt`](http://php.net/getopt).